# Why does this whitespace matter in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Given the code below (two 50% width divs, inside a 100% width container), why does the whitespace after the closing tag of div "bar" affect the rendering (in Chrome and FireFox at least)?

```
<style>
* {
border:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 0px silver;
}
.foo {
width: 100%;
}
.bar {
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        ...a new customer
    <!-- the whitespace between the following divs affects rendering - why? -->
    </div> <div class="bar">
        ...an existing customer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: The answer is, because they're inline blocks. But you already knew they were, so what is the problem? That's just how they behave. If you don't want a space, don't type a space!